# cmake qt6: unresolved external symbol “public: virtual struct QMetaObject”

Tags: qt, cmake

I am building qt6 project with cmake. I want to generate a library with QWidget, and the code is:

```
    #ifndef GLOBAL_EXPORTS
        #define GLOBAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define GLOBAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif // !GLOBAL_EXPORTS

class GLOBAL_EXPORT SWidgets : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SWidgets();
};
```

In compiling, the vs reports:

```
 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const SWidgets::staticMetaObject"
```

The bug can be solved by copy moc file. But, it is inconvenient because I have many qt relative library.

In addition, I have add `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC 1)`, and it do not work.

I have upload the code in github (https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/cmake_qt).

How to solve this bug by cmake? Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

---

Update: sorry for uploading code to github.

1. First, I define my `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` in a `Global.h` file:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_EXPORTS_H
#define GLOBAL_EXPORTS_H


#if (WIN32)
    #ifndef GLOBAL_EXPORTS
        #define GLOBAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define GLOBAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif // !GLOBAL_EXPORTS

#else
    #define GLOBAL_EXPORT 
#endif


#endif
```

2. Then I define my custom widget as:

```
#ifndef swidget_header_h
#define swidget_header_h

#include "Global.h"

#include <qwidget.h>
#include "qpushbutton.h"

class GLOBAL_EXPORT SWidgets : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SWidgets();
};

#endif // !swidget_header_h
```

Comment: "I have upload the code in github" - Stack Overflow requires **code** to be **in the question post** itself, not linked to outer site. Please, add relevant parts of the code to the question post. Your definition of the `GLOBAL_EXPORT` macro implies that users of your library will use additional `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` definition, so the library's functions will be marked with `__declspec(dllimport)`. While needing for a library's user to define a macro seems unusual (normally it is library which defines additional macro for export its symbols), I don't see definition of that macro in your code.

Comment: I have add the code to this question. The `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` is protected by `#ifndef-#define`.

Comment: "First, I define my `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` in a Global.h file" - You don't **define** `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` macro! In your header there are **definitions** (via `#define`) of `GLOBAL_EXPORTS_H` and `GLOBAL_EXPORT` macros and there are **checks** (with `#ifdef`) for `GLOBAL_EXPORTS_H` and `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` macros, but there is **no definition** of the `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` macro. Because of that `GLOBAL_EXPORT` macro is defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` even when your main project is compiled. The macro `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` should be defined in `CMakeLists.txt`, but you don't include its content into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev has pointed out, your handling of the `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` definition is wrong.

You should export the symbols if the `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` definition is set, therefore it should read (note: I changed `#ifndef` to `#ifdef`):

```
#ifdef GLOBAL_EXPORTS
    #define GLOBAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define GLOBAL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // !GLOBAL_EXPORTS
```

Then in your CMakeLists.txt of the `export_dll` project you should add a line defining `GLOBAL_EXPORTS`:

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC 1)
add_library(export_dll SHARED ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
set_target_properties(export_dll PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS GLOBAL_EXPORTS)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core Gui)
target_link_libraries(export_dll PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui)
```

By doing this `__declspec(dllexport)` will be added to the symbols when creating the DLL and every consumer of the DLL will automatically get the symbols with a proper `__declspec(dllimport)` set.

Comment: Thank you very much. `set_target_properties(export_dll PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS GLOBAL_EXPORTS)` works.

Comment: Even the problem is solved, I still have a question. `#ifndef` is changed to `#ifdef` because `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` has been defined in `CMakeLists.txt`. If I don't include `set_target_properties(export_dll PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS GLOBAL_EXPORTS)` in `CMakeLists.txt`, `#ifndef` would make `__declspec(dllexport)` be added to the symbols. So, I think the bug is not caused by `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` definition, because the code is ok if I remove `Q_OBJECT`. So, what's the meaning of `set_target_properties(export_dll PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS GLOBAL_EXPORTS)` except to define `GLOBAL_EXPORTS`?

Comment: if you use `#ifndef` and don't define `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` in your CMakeLists.txt **every** consumer of your DLL (even you in your executable's CMakeLists.txt) needs to add `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` to his definitions. That's highly inconvenient and contrary to the way almost all developers do.

Comment: To answer the question from your last comment: there is no further meaning in the command than to **set** the `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` property. An equivalent command that achieves the same but would **append** its definitions would be `target_compile_definitions(export_dll PRIVATE GLOBAL_EXPORTS)`

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. But, I don't understanding the meaning: `every consumer of your DLL needs to add GLOBAL_EXPORTS`. Actually, if I remove `Q_OBJECT`, the dll can be correctly generated, and it can be imported by `target_link_libraries(helloworld PRIVATE export_dll)`.

Comment: The error you were facing results from the missing `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` definition for your **executable** project. If you add that to your executable's CMakeLists.txt, the error disappears and the DLL is properly linked to your executable. That's what I meant with every executable needs this definition then if you do it the way as in your original project. The way I proposed does it the other way round, it defines `GLOBAL_EXPORTS` only for your **DLL** and does not need to set it for the executable. Your executable is one of the consumers of the DLL.

Comment: But, why it is OK if I remove `Q_OBJECT`? If I remove `Q_OBJECT`, the code would correctly generate a dll (name: `export_dll`), and I can import `export_dll` in other modules.

Comment: I don't know exactly. But I guess adding Q_OBJECT needs MOC preprocessing the class and that adds a bunch of  addtitional static methods that are not properly exported then.